# QML Screen Coordinates of Component

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick

If I have a simple, self-contained QML application, I can get the absolute screen coordinates of a component by saying

```
Component.onCompeted: {    
    var l = myThing.mapToItem(null, 0, 0)
    console.log("X: " + l.x + " y: " + l.y)
}
```

where myThing is the id of any other component in the file. However, if this file gets incorporated into another QML file and the component it defines is reused, I don't get the screen coordinates anymore; I get the local coordinates relative to the component where the statements above are executed.

How can I get the absolute screen coordinates of items?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
Component.onCompleted: {
    var globalCoordinares = myThing.mapToItem(myThing.parent, 0, 0)
    console.log("X: " + globalCoordinares.x + " y: " + globalCoordinares.y)
}
```

where `myThing.parent` is your main compontent.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have access to the main component where this widget will be used.

Comment: You're right. I tested it with `myThing.parent` which works in case the parent QML element fills the whole window. You can also use `myThing.parent.parent` if that is your root element. Not very nice and maintainable but it works.

Comment: @PaulCarlisle, There is exist way to access different QMLs using `import`. 
`import "../Path/To/Parent/" as ParentOfMyThing`
Then, should be available following thing: `ParentOfMyThing.someId`

Comment: The main component can be made global using dynamic scoping, just have a `property Window vroot : id_root`, then `vroot` will be available for the entire application.

Comment: `Item`s should have a `mapToGlobal` method. Further you can always access the toplevel `Item` with `ApplicationWindow.contentItem` if you use `ApplicationWindow` to create your window. I think `Window` is also an attached property to get the Window in which your Item is instantiated. (That is, nowadays. Might be different for 2014 Qt)

Answer (score 3):

Since Qt 5.7, there is [Item.mapToGlobal](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#mapToGlobal-method):

```
Component.onCompleted: {
    var globalCoordinates = mapToGlobal(0, 0)
    console.log("X: " + globalCoordinates.x + " y: " + globalCoordinates.y)
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this apparently doesn't work on delegates...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick and very dirty solution. Note: This has only been lightly tested but so far seems to work. I would not recommend using this in production applications as it's a complete hack and likely to break at some point.

```
ApplicationWindow {
    id: mainWindow
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    x: 150.0
    y: 150.0
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Rectangle {
        id: lolRect
        height: 50
        width: 50
        anchors.centerIn: parent;

        Component.onCompleted: {

            function getGlobalCordinatesOfItem(item) {

                // Find the root QML Window.
                function getRootWindowForItem(item) {
                    var cItem = item.parent;
                    if (cItem) {
                        return getRootWindowForItem(cItem);
                    } else {

                        // Path to the root items ApplicationWindow
                        var rootWindow = item.data[0].target;
                        if (rootWindow && rootWindow.toString().indexOf("ApplicationWindow") !== -1) {
                            return rootWindow;
                        } else {
                            console.exception("Unable to find root window!");
                            return null;
                        }
                    }
                }

                // Calculate the items position.
                var rootWindow = getRootWindowForItem(item);
                if (rootWindow) {
                    return Qt.point(rootWindow.x + lolRect.x,
                                    rootWindow.y + lolRect.y);
                } else {
                    return null;
                }
            }

            // Print the result.
            console.log(getGlobalCordinatesOfItem(this));
        }
    }
}
```