# QML : is it possible to obtain the application window's screen coordinate?

Tags: qml

I have an application that the entire application window is drag gable between on screen.

Is there anyway to find out the the coordinate of the application window relative to the screen is ?

I have a Window that needs to always appear below a button in the application window. But I am unable to retrieve its new screen x , y of the app if the user has drag the application to another part of the screen.

(link about qml window's x,y : http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-window-window.html#x-prop)

Trying the solution : [QML Screen Coordinates of Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21454393/qml-screen-coordinates-of-component)

always return 0,0 for me  (is it because the button is located at 0,0 relative to the application?)

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution myself.

I simply add the applicationwindow's x n y to to the dialog window's x and y + result of mapToItem.