# Qml: GridView.onReloaded signal

Tags: gridview, qml, qt5

I have QAbstractListModel in c++ code and connected it with qml GridView of Butons by means of

```
QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
QQmlContext* context = engine.rootContext();
context->setContextProperty("keyboardModel", _keyboardModel);
```

The main goal is get global coordinates of Buttons in c++ code. For this purposes i find this Buttons with `QQuickItem::childItems()` function and get final coordinates with `mapToGlobal()`.

Now, when i changed c++ model, qml GridView changed too. But, i cannot catch moment, when hierarchical QQuickItem tree fully refreshed (It needed for correct working  `QQuickItem::childItems()`)

GridView's signals onAdd, on Remove doesn't working, when new model has same amount of elements. GridView's signal onModelChanged triggered only, when i connected another model, not when i changed this one.

Is there any signal for recognizing, when hierarchical QQuickItem tree fully refreshed? Or there is any another method for dynamically getting Qml's object global coordinates?

Comment: Why would you want to have the coordinates of the Button in C++? Usually you have the data model in C++, and the View in QML. The data model should be view agnostic. Further you *can* but *should not* query QML from C++. Let the QML side tell the C++ side what C++ needs to know.

Comment: I should send it to another app.

Comment: A `GridView` uses dynamic instantiation, which means, you can't be sure, all `Buttons` defined in your model will be instantiated at every point in time. Further the `GridView` is a `Flickable` so the positions will change, when flicking, where you will have a lot of changes for tons of objects. How will you (conceptually) handle this? This is, because in your question you only handle *removal and addition* instead of flicking around. If it is rather static, you should consider a `Repeater` and a `Grid` instead.

Comment: I'd like to wait when flicking, or moving end's, and will find all Buttons in hierarchical QQuickItem tree, because i sould send correct coordinates, only when they don't changed for some time. I used Grid earlier, but catch some problems with it. Is there any signal, that qml's  GridView ends rebuilding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no signal for *when the GridView is rebuilt*

However the `GridView` has a property `moving` and the signal `movementEnded`

I would have each `Button` in your `GridView` connected to this signal. Further handle the `Component.onCompleted` of the `Button`. This Signal is fired when ever the `Button` is (re)created.

Now you expose a `Q_INVOCABLE` in some C++ object, that takes the required information as parameters. Let's say, its signature is

```
void reportPosition(QString name, int x, int y)
```

Now in the `Button` you have:

```
id: myGridView
delegate: Button {
    Component.onCompleted: {
        var p = mapToGlobal(x, y)
        myCppObject.reportPosition(objectname, p.x, p.y)
    }
    Connections {
        target: myGridView
        onMovementEnded: {
        var p = mapToGlobal(x, y)
        myCppObject.reportPosition(objectname, p.x, p.y)
    }
}
```

With this we achieved:

- C++ gets to know the position of all created Buttons when their movement has ended
- C++ gets to know the position of all newly created Buttons upon creation (guard it with `if (!moving) [...]` if you don't want the position of newly created Buttons, when they are moving)
- You don't need to query QML from C++ but have QML report to C++

> This is just an outline of the idea. I don't have the means to test it right now, so there might be errors.

Comment: mapToGlobal is a C++ function. I used it, but only, when i already have QQuickItem pointer on Button. As i know, there is no elegant and clear way to do it in qml (for example this solution is dirty, as author said https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21454393/qml-screen-coordinates-of-component)

Comment: [`mapToGlobal()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#mapToGlobal-method) is a C++ function exposed to QML by every `Item`

Comment: Of course you can also call the function and pass the Button itself to C++ if you prefer to have a object pointer. That is entirely up to you!